# converting categorical variables to be used in sklean

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, slice, sparse-matrix, dummy-variable

I created a sparse matrix using pd.get_dummies function. The matrix I have is 700M rows * 400 columns, I don't think it is that large compared to lots of problems other people are solving. But slicing into train, val, test set can take forever. (I will use logistic regression and random forest to do the prediction, which support sparse matrix. )Is there anyway to efficiently slicing a sparseDataFrame or for the whole process I am doing, it should be improved in anyway?

Given an example,

This is the list of columns I have before transforming categorical variable into dummy variables :

```
[u'a.exch', u'a.is_mobile', u'a.os_family', u'a.os_major', u'a.ua_family', u'a.ua_major', u'a.creative_id', u'a.creative_format',u'a.banner_position', u'a.day_hour_etc', u'b.country', u'b.connspeed',u'b.home_bus']
```

This is the number of unique values in each column:

```
a.exch 14
a.is_mobile 2
a.os_family 21
a.os_major 35
a.ua_family 49
a.ua_major 56
a.creative_id 30
a.creative_format 3
a.banner_position 6
a.day_hour_etc 4
b.country 94
b.connspeed 9
b.home_bus 3
```

After using pd.get_dummies, it has 300+ columns, for example

```
a.exch_1, a.exch_2, ..., b.home_bus1, b.home_bus2
```

I set the pd.get_dummies(input_df, sparse=True) because otherwise it will raise memory error. But now with this sparse representation, everything is really slow.

Update: to split into train, val and test, just randomly split into 3 parts with 6:2:2

Comment: can you provide a simple subset that shows: 1) how your data are structured; 2) what criteria you're using to determine which records are e.g., training vs validating; and 3) which methods you're using to slice the dataframe.

Comment: in my opinion 700M rows is **way** too big for sklearn, tbh i've never modelled with a dataset larget than 100K rows

Comment: Because I am running logistic regression and random forest, what else package you would recommend? I thought it would be a little bit over to run a 700M rows in Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 700M rows of data set is huge. And, by using get dummes you are almost making it 20 times larger.

Use `df.column =pd.factorize(df.column)[0]`

or

[`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html)

I not sure about performance but it will not be as worse as get_dummies, since this will not create 380+ columns. 
I guess, sub-setting is start of problems next would be training model will run forever with this much of data.